# Imagemagick problem when loading a png file

Tags: c++, macos, png, imagemagick

I've compiled the latest version of imagemagick for the mac and I get the assertion below when I load a particular png file. This is a bit of a hassle as it crashes the program in debug mode. Anyone ever seen this before? Any workarounds?

```
Assertion failed: (quantum_info->signature == MagickSignature), 
function DestroyQuantumInfo, file magick/quantum.c, line 215.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ["A Basic Introduction to PNG Features" - Integrity Checks](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngintro.html) -

> PNG supports three main types of integrity-checking to help avoid problems with file transfers and the like. The first and simplest is the eight-byte magic signature at the beginning of every PNG image. It will detect the most common type of file corruption: that due to the transfer of a binary file in text. On most systems, line-endings in text files are flagged by either a carriage-return character (CR), a line-feed character (LF), or both. Macintoshes use CRs; Unix systems use LFs; and all non-Unix PC systems (DOS, Windows 3.x/95/NT, OS/2) use CR/LF pairs.

Comment: Sounds reasonable - so in imagemagick's release mode I'll just hope that NULL/Invalid image is returned instead of assert crashing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is a bug in ImageMagick. I've tried using GraphicksMagick and it worked fine. The bug should be fixed on the next release of ImageMagick.

Comment: Still seems to happen in 2019, with ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16